# Запятая после ТАК

Tags: синтаксис

Нужна ли запятая после ТАК в подобных случаях и почему?
Многие продукты не всегда являются полезными. Так, сливочное масло противопоказано людям с повышенным...

Answer (score 6):

Вводное слово *так* в данном случае синонимично слову *например* и выделяется запятыми.